# DDD implementation with MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, domain-driven-design

I'm designing a DDD application and ran into an issue with MongoDB. Here I'll simplify the design.

Let's say I have the following class

```
public class Character : IEntity
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; private set; }

    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
    public string LastName { get; private set; }

    public Character(string name, string lastName)
    {
        Id = ObjectId.Empty.ToString();
        FirstName = name;
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    [BsonConstructor]
    public Character(string id, string name, string lastName)
    {
        Id = id;
        FirstName = name;
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    public virtual void UpdateName(string name)
    {
        FirstName = name;
    }

    public virtual void UpdateLastName(string lastName)
    {
        LastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

I also have the following request handler class to handle UpdateName requests:

```
public class UpdateCharacterNameHandler : IUpdateCharacterNameHandler 
{
    private readonly ICharacterRepository _characterRepository;

    public GetMyCharactersHandler(ICharacterRepository characterRepository)
    {
        _characterRepository= characterRepository;
    }

    public async Task<Result<Character> UpdateCharacterName(string id, string name)
    {
        var character = await _characterRepository.GetCharacterAsync(id);
        character.UpdateName(name);

        await _characterRepository.UpdateAsync(character);

        return Result.Ok(character);
    }
}
```

Since handler class itself doesn't know what exactly changed in the Character class, it only calls the update method of repository, which has the following implementation:

```
public async Task<Character> Update(Character character)
{
    var filter = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<Character>()
        .Eq(x => x.Id, character.Id);

        return await _collection.FindOneAndReplaceAsync(
        filter,
        character,
        options:
            new FindOneAndReplaceOptions<Character, Character>
            {
                ReturnDocument = ReturnDocument.After
            });
}
```

This implementation works fine as long as there are no concurrent updates to Character object. The issue I have is when multiple requests come in, read initial state of Character, make their modifications. When this happens, later request just overrides the first because it's not aware that Character object in the DB was updated meanwhile.

I believe simplest solution to this problem is to creating a `UpdateFirstName` method in the repository and calling that instead from the `UpdateCharacterNameHandler`. But if I do that, I always have to keep domain object, handler and repository in sync. For example if I update the implementation of UpdateName method in the domain object to update a second property, I have to remember to update repository method to take that into account as well.

Is there a way to prevent concurrent updates to Character object from overwriting each other?

Comment: Shouldn't you await _characterRepository.UpdateAsync(character);?

Comment: @GHDevOps Yes, it's already awaited. I missed it while simplifying the code but re-added it now :)

Answer (score 0):

#### The domain's purpose

First, please remember the purpose of the domain layer which is to validate, when the user request a change in the application state, that such change does not violate your *business rules*. The domain purpose is *not* to detect changes on the object state for the persistence layer to update, that's the purpose of the **unit of work**.

In other words, the purpose of the `Character.UpdateName` method is to prevent your customers from changing the character's name into something that is would be deemed invalid by a **business analyst**. However, in your example there is no business rules to validate, so the domain layer is useless in your case.

Let's consider there would be one for the sake of the conversation, though.

#### Confusing persistence and domain models

Also, you are confusing the persistence model and the domain model, with your persistence layer being a simple BSON serialization of your domain model. This allows a very simple implementation of your persistence layer. One drawback, however, is that you tend to write a single unified domain model rather than a polysemic domain model.

A polysemic domain model allows different representations of the same persistence data, with different level of details depending on what each use case need. When using a single domain model, you need to design your classes so that they include *all* data from the store, so any use case can manipulate the concept. This tends to make your domain classes larger than needed, resulting in larger data queries from the store than what you actually need, and not taking advantage of the powerful projection capabilities of MongoDB.

In other words, in your example you read the LastName of the character although you don't need that for your business use case, which is to update the FirstName. This causes a "granularity discrepancy" between your domain layer and your persistence layer. Normally the persistence store should manipulate smaller subsets of data than the busines layer, but in your case it's the other way around.

#### Handling the discrepancy

In your case, the persistence store handles the data at the `Character` BSON document level, which is larger that the `Character.FirstName` manipulated by your use case. This means one of the intermediate layer must "compensate" and handle the data that is in the persistence store but not in the use case. The whole operation, however must happen within a transactional so there is no concurrency problems.

The best practice around this compensation is to favor the component closest to the data, so you minimize network traffic and maximize the lock's efficiency. This, in turn, limits the impact on the overall performance of the system. Try to have the database to do the job for you and if that is not possible do it in the persistence layer.

I'm not experienced with MongoDB but it seems you can do in place document updates. If that is not supported, you'll have to implement, in the persistence layer, a method that opens a transaction, gets the document, update the value, and stores the updated document. However, as you noted, this will provoke a granularization of the persistence layer, which will be costly to implement and maintain.

Also, adding a transaction or a lock in the application will hinder your system's performance, causing a bottleneck when accessing the database. That is quite not the point of using a MongoDB storage.

#### Generalization

Since the problem is the *discrepancy* of the granularity, not the granularity itself, there is a second option: align the smaller use case to the larger persistence store instead of the opposite. Instead of offering an UpdateCharacterName use case to clients, propose an UpdateCharacter use case. This is actually extremely simple to implement:

```
public class Character : IEntity
{
  public string Id { get; init; }
  public string FirstName { get; private set; }
  public string LastName { get; private set; }
  // add other properties from the BSON document

  // implement business rules validation here
  // throw a business rule exception if violated
}
```

```
public class CharacterRepository : ICharacterRepository
{
  public async Task<Character> UpdateAsync(Character character)
  {
    var filter = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<Character>()Eq(x => x.Id, character.Id);
    var options = new FindOneAndReplaceOptions<Character, Character> { ReturnDocument = ReturnDocument.After };
    return await _collection.FindOneAndReplaceAsync( filter, character, options);
  }
}
```

```
public class UpdateCharacterHandler : IUpdateCharacterHandler
{
  private readonly ICharacterRepository characterRepository;

  public async Task<Result<Character>> UpdateCharacter(UpdateCharacterQuery query)
  {
    var character = await characterRepository.GetCharacterAsync(id);
    // redacted code to update the domain
    await characterRepository.UpdateAsync(character);
    return Result.Ok(character);
  }
}
```

And now, the client must send the full target state for the whole `Character` entity, which means:

1- the client is now responsible for the concurrency;

2- the service has a more RESTful design.

#### How to handle multiple clients concurrency

If you have multiple clients that are susceptible to do concurrent updates on the same object, then you should consider implementing the [If-Unmodified-Since](https://www.mscharhag.com/api-design/rest-concurrent-updates) pattern in your service